# Delete rows in R based on length of a column

Tags: r, subset

I have a data set in R that has 4 columns: size of turtle hatchlings, number of nests, years, beach.

I want to create a new data frame, excluding the nests for which I measured less than 10 hatchlings. So I need to exclude rows based on the length of the column Size, for unique combinations of "Year", "Beach" and "Nest".
Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `data.table`.  Convert the 'data.frame' to 'data.table' (`setDT(df1)`), grouped by 'Year', 'Beach', 'Nest', we subset the groups where the `length` of `unique` elements of "Hatchling_Number" is greater than or equal to 10

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df1)[, if(uniqueN(Hatchling_Number)>=10) .SD, by = .(Year, Beach, Nest)]
```

or in case there are no duplicate "Hatchling_Number" per each group, we can use `.N >=10` for subsetting.

```
setDT(df1)[, if(.N >=10) .SD, by = .(Year, Beach, Nest)]
```